# html input box minimum and decimal values

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<input  id="stockiboundqty0"  min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" step="any"  autocomplete="off" type="number" placeholder="Enter Quantity"/>
<button onclick="alertdialog()">submit</button>
<script>
function alertdialog()
{
alert(document.getElementById("stockiboundqty0").value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### what do i have

1.my input box minimum value is zero and 'step any' will allow decimal too

### problem

*if i enter '.2' it allows  it takes minimum value 0 if i enter 0.2 it takes as 0.2

### what do i needed

1.i need to let user enter .2 and takes value as 0.2  with the input box minimum 'value=0' and with step 'any'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the oninput handler.  That is preventing you from using a leading decimal point.

```
<input 
  id="stockiboundqty0" 
  min=0 
  step="0.1" 
  autocomplete="off" 
  type="number" 
  placeholder="Enter Quantity"
/>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input 
  id="stockiboundqty0"
  min=0
  step="0.1"
  autocomplete="off"
  type="number"
  placeholder="Enter Quantity"
 />
</body>
</html>
```

should work